# How do I find the values of the x and y coordinates based on the angle?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I find the value of **X** and **Y**? I have the angle formed by the point **P** and I know that the radius of the circle is 1000. How do I calculate this? Appreciate!

[image]

Comment: Wrong site. This site deals with the software Mathematica. You have asked about a homework problem in trigonometry. Start drawing triangles.

Comment: Do you know the sine and cosine functions?  You are changing from polar to Cartesian coordinates.  Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

$$\sin66^\circ = \frac{y}{r}$$

$$\cos66^\circ = \frac{x}{r}$$

Use a calculator to calculate $\sin66^\circ$, $\cos 66^\circ$.

$$0.91354545764 = \frac{y}{r}$$

$$0.40673664307 = \frac{x}{r}$$